# OpenFL/Lime install error (Haxe)

Tags: haxe, openfl

The following error occurs despite reinstalling Haxe. Haxe version is 3.1.3, Neko 2, Windows 8.1 64Bit

`C:\Users\J\Documents>haxelib run lime setup`

`Uncaught exception - load.c(181) : Module not found : run.n`

Any help appreciated.